# VS Code abre o pycharm durante execução de código

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

Boa tarde,

Ao rodar o comando abaixo no terminal do VSCODE, ele abre o pycharm para executar tal comando, não executando no próprio VSCODE.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já desinstalei o pycharm para testes. Então ao executar o comando ele executa o código corretamente, porém, ao digitar a resposta, este terminal aberto de forma externa, é encerrado.

Comment: Tentou fazer `python area_circulo_v3.py`?

Comment: Provavelmente você definiu o `PyCharm` como o programa que deve abrir e/ou executar arquivos `.py`. Se realmente foi isso, você deve localizar o script que deseja abrir com o VSCode, clicar com o botão direito do mouse, clicar sobre a opção `Abrir com`, e escolher o programa `VSCode`. A partir desse momento, todos os scripts `.py` serão abertos pelo `VSCode`.

Comment: Você ir na pasta onde está o arquivo.py e dar `code .` que ele vai abrir aquela pasta dentro do visual studio e lá dentro você poderá simplesmente executar o programa. Porém você pode só digitar no seu terminal: `python area_circulo_v3.py` e ele vai executar o código também ao invés de abrir o pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Você usa em um ambiente virtual? Se não, deve ser isso, pois o seu pycharm seria o interpretador padrão para arquivos fora do venv(ambiente virtual), tenta criar um no seu vscode vê se resolve, tenta criar uma pasta separada também, de arquivos do vscode e arquivos do pycharm para não conflitarem